# Adding a character to every other text line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a huge (ca. 20G) text file which contains millions of passages (a.k.a. paragraphs) with headers. Headers and paragraphs are always one line each, e.g.,

> Sunshine
>   This is a sunny day.
>   Darkness
>   A cave is a dark place.

What I try to come up with is a terminal command which goes through the text and adds a '>' in front of every header, i.e., every *odd-numbered line* (lines 1, 3, 5, …), e.g.,

> >Sunshine
>   This is a sunny day.
>   >Darkness
>   A cave is a dark place.

Any ideas?

If this is relevant:  the above text was just an example. Most of the headers are MD5s, followed by a DNA sequence ('paragraph'), e.g.,

> 0002ebd9ca12d6b69dfc3066356fc299
>   CATTAACCATTGGATACCTTCGGGTATATCCCATCCGTGTCTACATACTCTTGTTGCTTTGGCAGGCCGTGGTCACACACTGTGGGCTATGCCTGCATGTGCCTGCCAGAGGACCA

… which I'm trying to convert to

> >0002ebd9ca12d6b69dfc3066356fc299
>   CATTAACCATTGGATACCTTCGGGTATATCCCATCCGTGTCTACATACTCTTGTTGCTTTGGCAGGCCGTGGTCACACACTGTGGGCTATGCCTGCATGTGCCTGCCAGAGGACCA

Comment: Are blank lines in your input?

Comment: You say "in front", but the `>` is added as the 2nd character of your examples. Can you clarify where you want it and also, are the single quotes in your examples part of the text file or just a formatting slip-up in your post?

Comment: sorry, for the confusion. I only want > in front of every second line beginning with the first. > was removed when I created this post and the text was put in the greyed out box. so I used ' to be able to show >

Comment: no blank lines in my file

Answer (score 4):

To edit every other (a.k.a. every second) line, starting with the first, with GNU `sed`, do

```
sed '1~2s/^/>/' your_file
```

This will write the modified file to the standard output. 
I.e., if you type *just* the above, the modified file will display on the screen. 
You can put this into a new file by *redirecting the output* with a `>`; e.g.,

```
sed '1~2s/^/>/' your_file > your_new_file
```

or, if you want to modify your existing file, use `-i`:

```
sed -i '1~2s/^/>/' your_file
```

Comment: `sed -i` on a 20g file is a really terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
sed 's/^/>/;n' < file.in > file.out
```

Answer (score 2):

Another POSIX answer:

```
paste -d'>\n' /dev/null - - <infile
```

It gets:

```
>Sunshine
This is a sunny day.
>Darkness
A cave is a dark place.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1,${s/^/>/g;n;n;n}' filename
```

**Testing**

```
cat filename
'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place

'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place

'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place
```

After I run the command, I get the output as,

```
sed '1,${s/^/>/g;n;n;n}' new
>'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

>'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place

>'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

>'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place

>'Sunshine

'This is a sunny day.

>'Darkness

'A cave is a dark place
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am on a Mac and had to change to a linux system to check your command. it seems to not work for me. a '>' was added to the first line and then after 7 lines or so

Comment: @Ramesh @BSP , please at first clean your data from blank lines via : `egrep -v "^$" yoursourcedata > cleaneddata.txt`

Answer (score 0):

With no blank lines between each line and no `'` character at the start:

```
$ awk '{print ((NR%2)? ">":"") $0}' passages.txt
```

gives:

```
>Sunshine
This is a sunny day.
>Darkness
A cave is a dark place.
```

Also, going by your responses to all the answers here, your input file isn't single lines with a Line Feed character at the end (`\n`). It might be worth checking it's source.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried both commands. My file is not double spaced. The first one adds the '>' only every second header. The second one also every second header but also adds a an additional line break

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you could try something like,

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 1 {sub(/^/,">")} {print}' filename
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line

Comment: it seems to not work for me. a '>' was added to the first line and then after 7 lines or so. as i am new to unix commands i also dont see why..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/\v(.*\n){2}/> &/|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `\v` turn on magic
4. `x` save and close